# Application autostart under certain tag in awesome-wm

Tags: awesome-wm

I have read [Setting windows layout for a specific application in awesome-wm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120399/setting-windows-layout-for-a-specific-application-in-awesome-wm).Now I want to do this under certain tag during autostart.
For example:

> > I turn on my pc.Apps like "firefox","terminal" will automatically run under tag 1."  "mplayer" will run under tag 2. "xchat" will run under tag 3. They all autostart.
> >
> > I don't want "firefox" always under tag 1. I could run firefox under any tags I want.I just need it run under tag 1 when computer is first turned on.So code below couldn't be used.

```
awful.rules.rules = {
-- All clients will match this rule.
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" },
 properties = { tag = tags[1][2]}}, --,switchtotag=true} },
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [shifty](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Shifty)- there you can specify the tab for the application, but you can still move it to a different tab.

Comment: Thank you.Shifty is very convenient.

Comment: [tyrannical](https://github.com/Elv13/tyrannical) can cleanly handle dynamic tag management and application launching rules

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked on the  awesome wiki pages? I think this is what you are lookin for:

```
   function run_once(prg,arg_string,pname,screen)
    if not prg then
        do return nil end
    end

    if not pname then
       pname = prg
    end

    if not arg_string then 
        awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep -f -u $USER -x '" .. pname .. "' || (" .. prg .. ")",screen)
    else
        awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep -f -u $USER -x '" .. pname .. " ".. arg_string .."' || (" .. prg .. " " .. arg_string .. ")",screen)
    end
end

run_once("xscreensaver","-no-splash")
run_once("pidgin",nil,nil,2)
run_once("wicd-client",nil,"/usr/bin/python2 -O /usr/share/wicd/gtk/wicd-client.py")
```

This code is from the [awesome wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Autostart). You can pass the screen as an argument to this function. For more details look at the link above. If you want to open the window in a special tag on a screen you could give the window a special name (exp. "startup") and then create a rule to launch only the instances named "startup" on the screen.

Example:

```
run_once("firefox","startup, nil, 1)

...
 rule = { class = "Firefox", instance = "startup" }, properties = {tag = tags[2]}},
...
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @nyquist, I was searching for how to do this. I will try this soon.

Answer (score 3):

I created a small gist for doing that task with pure lua within the capabilities of Awesome and no need for plugins!

https://gist.github.com/Flowkap/8858434