# The spawn command is opening a couple of programs in the wrong tag

Tags: awesome-wm

Here is what I have in my `rc.lua`:

```lua
awful.spawn.once("firefox", { tag = "1"; })
awful.spawn.once(terminal, { tag = "2"; })
awful.spawn.once("signal-desktop", { tag = "9"; })
```

Firefox correctly appears on tag 1.
Terminal correctly appears on tag 2.
But `signal-desktop` appears on tag 1 instead of tag 9.
I saw various staff on Google that suggest it is a problem with `startup_id` and not with AwesomeWM. I also saw this thingy in the documentation: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#client.startup_id.
But it does not work, `signal-desktop` still appears on tag 1, and I get the following error from AwesomeWM:

[image]

Please help :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application autostart under certain tag in awesome-wm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019921/application-autostart-under-certain-tag-in-awesome-wm)

Comment: No, it does not, but thank you :-)

Comment: Forcing all signal window to be on a tag is not working ?

Comment: AwesomeWM gev here: This is getting worst and worst. For some time, a lot of application startup_id have become unreliable. Years ago, most window manager and desktop environments supported this, but one by one they moved to `systemd`. Since nobody test the old protocol, each application and toolkit eventually broke it. Right now, `awful.spawn` doesn't support `systemd` (or other `cgroup` managers). I have some half working patches and plan to merge them before v4.4, but this is not done yet. So the environment variable hack is your best bet for now. Sorry for the bug, it's not us.

Comment: @EmmanuelLepageVallee
Thank you very much for your answer. I completely understand now. It's not an issue with AwesomeWM.

It's this damn `systemd` again. Sorry for starting a flame war. Had to get it out of my system(d) :-)

>> Sorry for the bug, it's not us.
Please do not apologize! You are doing an exceptionally wonderful job!!!! Thank you!!!!

>> So the environment variable hack is your best bet for now
Just to clarify, please send a link for what you mean.

Comment: @EmmanuelLepageVallee One more thing, please. Would mind making your comment as an answer and I will mark it accepted. This is for googlers from the future. Or, if you prefer, I can self-answer this question.

Comment: @Ôrel No, it does not.